# Magento2 - Use placeholder {{base_url}} in multistore

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, database, base-url

In magento1 you can set the base url's in a multistore like this:
`{{base_url}}en/`, `{{base_url}}nl/`, etc.

Trying that in Magento 2 will result in the following Error:

> Invalid Base URL. Value must be a URL or one of placeholders: {{base_url}}

Is there a workaround to achieve this without editing the database directly?

What I want to achieve is to work with multiple developers in one database.

Comment: If you don't want to edit the database directly, is having to extend the core's source code an option for you?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I found the Solution.
**Just end your url with a /(Slash).**

Comment: Like `{{base_url}}/en/` ?

Comment: Yes Frank you can try with above code.Do not forget to add / at end of url.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced same issue and fixed to add url with end `/ (Slash)`

For Example you can use url `https://www.example.com` instead `https://www.example.com/`

Hope it help!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, found a solution.

Just set every base url to `{{base_url}}`.

For example when you navigate to `https://url.extension/store_url` the base url is automatically set to that specific url.

So when you click on a link on that page the next page will be `https://url.extension/store_url/next_page`

In this way you can work with multiple developers in one database :)

Answer (score 0):

Check also if you have some special chart in base_url or some `_` (underscore), if so, delete it or replace it with a hyphen.